# LIsting all the text files in a folder and writing information to excel sheet

Tags: excel, vbscript, automation, export-to-excel

There are certain text files in a folder, i.e, file1.txt ; file2.txt; ... Also, there is an array of strings which can be stored as studs(i) in VBScript. My objective is to verify if each string (studs(i)) is present in each of the text file (fileN.txt) and write the information to an excel sheet with the strings elements in the rows and filenames(file1, file2, file3,....) in the columns. I need a Vbscript which automates this process. Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Are you sure you want VBScript, or do you mean Excel-VBA? Just checking.

Comment: To be clear, A VBScript which automates this process..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this helps

- execute findstr command
- capture result in System.Collections.ArrayList
- result can then be stored in excel

**Code**

```
Function findFilesThatContain(searchText, filePath)
    Set DataList = CreateObject _
    ("System.Collections.ArrayList")
    Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Set objExecObject = objShell.Exec("findstr /M """ & searchText & """ " & filePath)
    Do While Not objExecObject.StdOut.AtEndOfStream
        fileLoc = objExecObject.StdOut.ReadLine()
        'Wscript.Echo searchText&","&fileLoc      
        DataList.Add fileLoc
    Loop
    Set findFilesThatContain = DataList
End Function

Sub saveToExcel(searchText, searchPath, strExcelPath)
    Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    If (Err.Number <> 0) Then
        On Error GoTo 0
        Wscript.Echo "Excel application not found."
        Wscript.Quit
    End If
    objExcel.Workbooks.Add
    Set objSheet = objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    objSheet.Name = "Search Result"
    Dim i,j
    j = 1
    For Each searchText in searchTexts
        Dim files
        Set files = findFilesThatContain (searchText, searchPath)
        i = 1
        objSheet.Cells(i, j).Value = searchText
        For Each path in files
            Wscript.Echo searchText&","&path
            i = i + 1
            objSheet.Cells(i, j).Value = path
        Next
        j = j + 1
    Next
    objSheet.Range("1:1").Font.Bold = True
    objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs strExcelPath, 56
    objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close
    objExcel.Application.Quit
End Sub
Dim strExcelPath
strExcelPath = "c:\test.xls"
Dim searchPath 
searchPath = "E:\bin\bat\*.bat"
Dim searchTexts(2)
searchTexts(0)="pushd"
searchTexts(1)="if"
saveToExcel searchText, searchPath, strExcelPath
```

**output**

[image: table]

Comment: best way to learn is by experimenting! Try to record some macros and see the generated code. refer to scriptingguy:http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/bb410849